# Django Deployment with nginx - gunicorn from another server

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy my `Django Project` through different application server : `Apache2`, `Nginx/gunicorn`, ...

It works fine with `Apache2` or `Nginx`, but I would like to dissociate these application server with my `Django Projet`. I would like to get an environment like this :

- Server 1 (172.30.10.92) : Django Project & wsgi
- Server 2 (172.30.10.93) : Nginx/gunicorn

Why ? Because later I will have some Django applications, but I would like to use just one application server.

I think I'm making a mistake with my configuration files syntax.

I have in **/etc/nginx/sites-available/DatasystemsCORE.conf** :

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name 172.30.10.92; 

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
            root http://172.30.10.92:/var/www/html/;
    }

    location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://172.30.10.92/unix:/var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/dscore.sock;
    }
}
```

**server_name :** Is it IP adress from Django server or nginx server ? I think it's the first one but I'm not sure.

**proxy_pass :** I think there is an issue in my path

Then, I'm executing this command :

```
gunicorn --daemon --workers 3 --bind 172.30.10.92/unix:/var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/dscore.sock 172.30.10.92:/var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/DatasystemsCORE.wsgi
```

One more time, I thing there is a syntax problem because I'm getting `502 Bad Request`

How I can add IP address from a distant Django server there ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found How to solve my issue and I made a tutorial (based on my case) in order to help everyone who would like to make the same thing.

My file is there : [Download tutorial file](http://www.sendbox.fr/b3812d3d07403764/Django:wsgi:Gunicorn:Nginx.pdf)

But this is the same tutorial written in English.

**My Django IP server : 172.30.10.92**

**My Nginx IP server : 172.30.10.93**

### 1- Install and Configure wsgi (located on Django server)

WSGI is a file created with your Django project.

The file is located in `/path/to/your/project/Myproject/wsgi.py`

We have to edit this file like this :

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

import sys sys.path.append('/var/www/html/Myproject')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Myproject.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

### 2- Install and Configure gunicorn/supervisor (located on Django server)

In order to install gunicorn/supervisor, you have to execute in your shell :

```
pip install gunicorn
pip install supervisor
```

Then, you have to create a new file in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/Myproject.conf` which looks like this :

```
[program:Myproject]
command = /home/valentin/.virtualenvs/MyprojectEnv/bin/gunicorn Myproject.wsgi:application --name "Myproject" --workers=4 --bind=0.0.0.0:8080 -- user="valentin" --group="valentin" ; Command to start app
user = username #You have to replace by your username
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/supervisor.log
redirect_stderr = true
log
environment=LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8,LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8
```

I specified **port 8080** which is the communication port between my application server and my web server.

### 3- Edit hosts file on nginx server (located on nginx server)

You have to edit your hosts file located to `/etc/hosts` and add a new entry to your Django server :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost 
127.0.1.1 valentin 
172.30.10.92 Myproject

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts ::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

### 4- New config file in nginx repository (located on nginx server)

This new file should be placed in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/Myproject.conf`

```
 server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name Myproject;

    root /var/www/html/Myproject/;

    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/html/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://172.30.10.92:8080;
        }       
}
```

The IP address corresponds to my Django server address. I specified the listen port (8080), the path to my Django project & static directory.

Then, you have to create a symbolic link to **sites-enabled**.

After ths operation, restart nginx service :

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

### 5- Allow nginx IP address in Django (located on Django server)

You have to edit your **settings.py** file in order to allow nginx IP address in **ALLOWED_HOSTS** :

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '172.30.10.93', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]']
```

### 6- Finally execute gunicorn (located on Django server)

Finally, you have to start gunicorn. You should be inside your Django root project and execute :

```
gunicorn Myproject.wsgi:application --bind 172.30.10.92:8080
```

Now, in your browser, try to connect to your nginx server with the port :

```
http://172.30.10.93:8080
```

It works !

PS : This tutorial works for me, if it doesn't work for you, maybe I missed something, or maybe you didn't make exactly like me ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do doesn't make any sense. You can certainly use a single nginx on a separate server, but gunicorn is the application server and belongs with the application.

There is no "Django server" so your first question is irrelevant. gunicorn will need to serve on a port, not a socket, and the nginx proxy_pass will point to that port.

Comment: OK, so I have to configure gunicorn into my "Django server" ("Django server" means virtual machine with my Django application). But I can  have nginx installed and configured in another server right ? 

Hum I didn't find up to know examples according to this configuration, so it's a but unclear for me.

Comment: Yes, nginx can forward to gunicorn running on the separate server, but as I say it needs to be via IP/port rather than via socket.

Comment: Ok, I have to see how I can configure my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/DatasystemsCORE.conf` file in order to use IP Port. Than I assume I just have to start nginx which will be connected to gunicorn, then gunicorn to wsgi and finally wsgi to my Django application ?