# Deploying django application with web server, app server and db server

Tags: django, deployment

This is my first django app I am deploying. I am looking at deploying the django app with Gunicorn, Nginx and PostgreSQL. There are three separate servers(Linux). I have installed Nginx on webserver, gunicorn on app and postgres on the db server. To connect the app I made changes to the settings.py. I added the IP of the Linux server[DB server which has postgres installed with roles db created] and once I migrated it showed error.

Comment: [Check this, how to setup Django project with PostgreSQL, Nginx and Gunicorn](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Please do a bit of research before asking such generic questions. There's lots of guides on how to do this. And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50062228/django-deployment-with-nginx-gunicorn-from-another-server) might help as well.

Comment: How do i connect postgres on db server to djnago app on webserver. I made chnages to the allowed_host in djnago app, I added ip on db server when i migrate it shows error